# Did Maradona ever score a goal with his right foot?

Tags: football

I was hearing one of Pele's declarations stating Maradona couldn't score goals with his right foot. I thought he was talking in general, but then I started to think about goals made by him with his right foot and I couldn't remember any. I made a little research about this and I couldn't find any goal scored by him with his right foot, even though I clearly didn't watch all 300+ goals he made in his career (I'm not sure if all of them were recorded on TV by the way).

I also remembered he used to kick the ball to the center of the field with his left foot even when he was in the right side of the field, giving the pass with a "Rabona" instead of with his right foot, because he was too much of a left-footed player. So, did he ever score a goal with his right foot, or did he never score one this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maradona scored with his right foot in 1993 for Newell's Old Boys in a friendly game against Emelec (at 7:18 in the video below).

I couldn't find official statistics, but some [questionable sources](https://www.discogs.com/group/thread/541302) include this breakdown:

> 320 with his left foot,
> 26 with his head,
> 6 with his right foot and
> 1 with his left hand

Comment: Good one! Out of curiosity: how did you find this? I checked quite a lot of sources, including YouTube videos, and could not find this data.

Comment: @fedorqui If you're talking about the goal, it was [in the news recently](https://tribuna.com/en/news/2020-11-29-tribute-done-right-messis-goal-vs-osasuna-incredibly-similar-to-maradonas-goal-for-newell/) when Messi scored a very similar goal against Osasuna wearing Newell's shirt as a tribute. The statistics I found on an obscure internet forum, I wasn't able to verify it and I have no idea where it comes from.

Comment: Hmm... I'm a bit skeptical of the fact that out of the 353 goals that he scored, Maradona only scored 6 with his right foot. If that's true: wow...

Comment: @OTStats It was said about Maradona many times that he only had his right leg to walk. He even gave passes from the right side of the field with his left foot by making a "rabona", which is a very complicated thing to do, but which also showed that he prefered to do something complicated with his left leg than using his right one.

Comment: He did not score with his left hand as it was the 'Hand of God', otherwise it would have been a hand-ball ;)

Answer (score 2):

Maradona scored two goals with his right foot playing for Boca Juniors in 1981, one against archrival River Plate (a true golazo) and another against Instituto (between the legs of the goalkeeper). Both goals can be seen here, at the 1:05 and 6:40 marks:

He also scored four goals with his right foot playing for Napoli. This can be seen on this video, at the 2:18, 8:12, 9:45, and 11:34 marks:

He also gave several assists with his right foot, including probably the most famous of all, the one to Caniggia against Brazil at the 1990 World Cup.